# How to resize the view in swift programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to resize a view in view controller. Default value of view is 60 on button press i change the height of the view. When i check it in debugger mode it shows the height of the new value but after few lines or in other function it automatically set back to default value which is 60 .

```swift
@IBAction func confirmButtonWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if confirmButton.titleLabel?.text == "Confirm pickup location" {
        if !(pickupLocationField.text?.isEmpty ?? false) && originLocation != nil {
            let frame = CGRect(x: searchesShadowView.frame.origin.x, y: searchesShadowView.frame.origin.y, width: searchesShadowView.frame.width, height: 115)

            self.searchesShadowView.frame = frame

            var imageView = UIImageView();
            var image = UIImage(named: "work25");
            imageView.image = image;
            dropoffLocationField.rightView = imageView;
            dropoffLocationField.rightViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always
        }
        else {
            showToast(with: "Select pick up location")
        }
    }
}
```

the other way i used

```swift
@IBAction func confirmButtonWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if confirmButton.titleLabel?.text == "Confirm pickup location" {
        if !(pickupLocationField.text?.isEmpty ?? false) && originLocation != nil {
            searchesShadowView.frame.size.height = 115
            var imageView = UIImageView();
            var image = UIImage(named: "work25");
            imageView.image = image;
            dropoffLocationField.rightView = imageView;
            dropoffLocationField.rightViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always
        }
        else {
            showToast(with: "Select pick up location")
        }
    }
}
```

also this `searchesShadowView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 115).isActive = true`

Comment: How did you set the height of the view? Did you use Interface Builder or programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should connect `IBOutlet` of the height constraint from `Interface Builder` and then you can change the `constant` of the height constraint like this ->

```swift
@IBAction func confirmButtonWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if confirmButton.titleLabel?.text == "Confirm pickup location" {

        if !(pickupLocationField.text?.isEmpty ?? false) && originLocation != nil {

        // You can change the value of the constraint
        searchesShadowHeightConstraint.constant = 115

        var imageView = UIImageView()
        var image = UIImage(named: "work25")
        imageView.image = image
        dropoffLocationField.rightView = imageView
        dropoffLocationField.rightViewMode = .always

    } else {
        showToast(with: "Select pick up location")
    }
    // Then you should update the layout
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to take constrain of height of your searchesShadowView.

[image: Image Outlet]

```
@IBAction func confirmButtonWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
       if confirmButton.titleLabel?.text == "Confirm pickup location" {
        if !(pickupLocationField.text?.isEmpty ?? false) && originLocation != nil {
            let frame = CGRect(x: searchesShadowView.frame.origin.x, y: searchesShadowView.frame.origin.y, width: searchesShadowView.frame.width, height: 115)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.heightConstrain.constant = 10
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }

            self.searchesShadowView.frame = frame

            var imageView = UIImageView();
            var image = UIImage(named: "work25");
            imageView.image = image;
            dropoffLocationField.rightView = imageView;
            dropoffLocationField.rightViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always
        }
        else {
            showToast(with: "Select pick up location")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create IBOutlet of height constraints of searchesShadowView.

```
 searchViewheightConstaints.constant = yourRequiredHeight
```

//if you are creating from Code use

```
searchesShadowView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code below.

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let searchesShadowView = UIView()
    let plusButton = UIButton()
    let minusButton = UIButton()
    var heightLayoutConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint?
    let value: CGFloat = 10.0

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        loadUIView()
        loadPlusButton(plusButton)
        loadMinusButton(minusButton)
    }

    func loadUIView()  {
        self.view.addSubview(searchesShadowView)
        searchesShadowView.backgroundColor = .red
        searchesShadowView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchesShadowView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 200).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchesShadowView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 50).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchesShadowView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -50).isActive = true
        heightLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchesShadowView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200)
        heightLayoutConstraint?.isActive = true
    }

    func loadPlusButton(_ button: UIButton) {
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        button.tag = 1
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        button.setTitle("+", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 100).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 50).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant:
            80).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30).isActive = true
    }

    func loadMinusButton(_ button: UIButton) {
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        button.tag = 0
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        button.setTitle("-", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 100).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -50).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant:
            80).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, delay: 0.2, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            if sender.tag == 1 {
                self.heightLayoutConstraint?.constant += self.value
            }else{
                self.heightLayoutConstraint?.constant -= ((self.heightLayoutConstraint?.constant ?? 0)-self.value) >= 0 ? self.value : 0
            }
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { (value) in }
    }
}
```